# Can I make a shared link in Mail.app appear above my signature?

Tags: mail.app, safari, email, macos, signature

When I click the Share arrow in Yosemite / Safari, then select 'Email this page' Mail.app opens a new email with my signature and the link below the signature:

[image: example screenshot]

I want the link to appear above my signature. Is there any way to change that?

I feel like the link used to be above my signature, but I can't find a preference that seems to affect the location. I tried the 'signature appears above quoted text' checkbox which some people implied could change this, but no dice.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the attached image when I select add Signature:

[image]

Do you have this? Does it work?

I'm using 10.10.x

Comment: I have that checkbox, yeah. Neither setting seems to affect link placement for me on Yosemite. I feel like this used to the job -- and some Google searching implied that it did.

Comment: hmm. could be a Yosemite bug. I will file a report to Apple. You can use feedback@apple.com

Comment: I used their Mac OS X Feedback webpage. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

No, but Mailbox for Mac does. it's free, but you need a Dropbox account to use.
http://www.mailboxapp.com/download/mac/

Don't forget to open Mail.app and go into settings and change the default email reader from Mail.app to Mailbox.app.

Comment: I'm hoping to stick with Mail.app, even if it means waiting for a fix.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately Mail.app hasn't changed much over the years and I imagine power user functionality is low on Apple's priorities.

Comment: @scoutelder: This is nowhere near power user functionality. This is basic functionality.

Comment: And, to be honest, the sharing features are recently added -- this seems to be one of the areas they /are/ focusing on.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is not the perfect solution, it maybe helps in your case.
I hope you don't mind writing some html code.

You can create a simple custom email template and apply it to your email after sharing the link from within Safari.

**Step 1: Prepare your template**
Open Mail.app and create a new email.
Go to the File menu and choose 'Save as Stationery ...' and named as desired.

**Step 2: Edit your template**
Open a Finder window.
From the menu, select 'Go to Folder ...', and paste this

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Application Support/Mail/Stationery/Apple/Contents/Resources/Custom/Contents/Resources
```

You should see your newly created template. Right-click (2-Finger-Tap on the Touchpad) the template and pick 'Show Package Content'.
Inside your template, follow the folder structure and you'll find a file named content.html .
This is your email template. Open it with your favorite text editor, e.g. TextWrangler, or, if you happen to have one, your HTML editor (I really love [Brackets](http://brackets.io)!).

Replace the content of that file with something like this:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body dir="auto" style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;" class="">

    <span contenteditable="true" apple-content-name="body">
        CONTENT
    </span>

    <br >
    <div>
        Your signature goes here
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Replace 'Your signature goes here' with ... well, your signature.
Don't forget to save the file. But keep it in your editor for further changes.

**Step 3: Share a page from within Safari**
When the email opens up, apply your new custom stationary. The rightmost button on top of the mail window opens the stationary pane.
You have to scroll down to find the 'Custom' section and within it your new template.
Click to apply. Your signature should now appear below the link, as it is the signature from the template.
[image: Mail.app stationary button]

**Step 4: Edit and repeat**
If it does not fit your needs, change the html code of the template until it does.
To reapply the template, pick another stationary for your email, then reselect your custom one.

For future shared links from Safari, just apply that stationary.